# How to align with printf in C

Tags: c, printf, alignment

so this is a simple problem but I can't figure out how. So how to align left or align-center with %(number)s? The default is align right with that syntax. Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    char *p, s[100];
    long n;
    int cmp,tesint;
    char tes[50],tes1[50],tes2[50];
    printf("tes  : ");
    fgets(tes,50,stdin);
    strtok(tes,"\n");
    printf("tesint : ");
    scanf("%d",&tesint);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("tes 1 : ");
    fgets(tes1,50,stdin);
    strtok(tes1,"\n");
    printf("tes 2 : ");
    fgets(tes2,50,stdin);
    strtok(tes2,"\n");
    printf("=======================================\n");
    printf("= tes s   : %25s =\n",tes);
    printf("= tes int : %25d =\n",tesint);
    printf("= tes 1   : %25s =\n",tes1);
    printf("= tes 2   : %25s =\n",tes2);
    printf("=======================================\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it:

```
tes  : Opan Lazuardi Prayoga
tesint : 20
tes 1 : Laki-laki
tes 2 : Bogor, Jawa Barat
=======================================
= tes s   :     Opan Lazuardi Prayoga =
= tes int :                        20 =
= tes 1   :                 Laki-laki =
= tes 2   :         Bogor, Jawa Barat =
=======================================

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 15.695 s
Press any key to continue.
```

And that is not expected output, I want to output like this:

```
tes  : Opan Lazuardi Prayoga
tesint : 20
tes 1 : Laki-laki
tes 2 : Bogor, Jawa Barat
=======================================
= tes s   : Opan Lazuardi Prayoga     =
= tes int : 20                        =
= tes 1   : Laki-laki                 =
= tes 2   : Bogor, Jawa Barat         =
=======================================
```

Or like this:

```
tes  : Opan Lazuardi Prayoga
tesint : 20
tes 1 : Laki-laki
tes 2 : Bogor, Jawa Barat
=======================================
= tes s   :   Opan Lazuardi Prayoga   =
= tes int :            20             =
= tes 1   :         Laki-laki         =
= tes 2   :     Bogor, Jawa Barat     =
========================================
```

I know I can do it manually with \t or with many spaces, but if do that the border '=' character in from "tes s" to "test 2" will not same. I have already searched for a similar question but I still don't get it. So I ask just to ask here to make it clear for me. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't mix `scanf()` and `fgets()` from `stdin` in the same code, unless you are 100% familiar with their behaviours. Note that `fflush(stdin)` which presumably is an attempt to kudge your way out, is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @WeatherVane so its better to use fgets even for number data? like integer,float,etc. If it's better, how to take the number to number data variables?As far as I know fgets will get the input to string variable first

Comment: Yes, and apply `sscanf` to the string. It's far easier to recover from invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-` flag in the format string to tell it to left justify.

```
printf("= tes s   : %-25s =\n",tes);
printf("= tes int : %-25d =\n",tesint);
printf("= tes 1   : %-25s =\n",tes1);
printf("= tes 2   : %-25s =\n",tes2);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it solve to left justify. But is there a specific syntax form align center?

Comment: @LearnerC No, nothing for center justification.